# How to add together duplicate values in columns?

Tags: r, math, statistics

I have three columns; loan_id, amount, date. I have 1,048,575 entries and I need to add together all the duplicates in loan_id column(there are different payments on the same loan_id) and in the second table the amount values should be added together matching with the loan_id.

Sample of how my data looks like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
aggregate(df$amount,list(df$loan_id),sum)
```

Comment: If I add those together, how can I make a separate table only with two columns, loan_id and amount? In the console, It shows me the first 500, but I need a table where the whole list is shown (75466 rows)

Comment: @asdf123 !!! That's only the print output. Save the results in an object and then operate on it arbitrarily.

Comment: yea but it says: [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 75466 rows ], it shows the first 500, but how can I see the whole list?

Comment: @asdf123 I don't know why you would want to see all that, but anyway use `options(max.print=1e5)` or some other number.

Comment: If I add those duplicates together I get the values in the console, but I need to make a separate data table with new variables

Answer (score 0):

So you want the total amount for each loan_id irrespective of date?

One way to do aggregate functions like this in R is by using the data.table package.

```
library(data.table)

# assuming you start with a data.frame

mydata = data.table(mydata)

mydata[,sum(amount), by=loan_id]
```